# How to run unittest in pycharm community v2018.3.6

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to run unit test in pycharm but not seeing an option in the context menu.. 
Please find as show below
[image]

Please help

Also, when I run from the following command from the console, '`python -m unittest login.py`' unit test are running but again if I run command '`python login.py`' actual test execution is not running.

How to run unit test and test execution from console or from pycharm IDE ..??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an existed run configuration (`login`) for this script so PyCharm suggests it instead of running tests. Either remove it from **Run | Edit configurations** and try to **right-click -> Run unittest** or use **Run | Run...** and select unittest there. Has it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pavel for respond, I have solved by renaming file name starts with 'test', it worked now, not sure if this is really the way to fix but it resolve my problem.